# Android application icon doesn't appear in the app list

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

Android application builds and runs in the BlueStacks emulator, but when I try it on my mobile device it installs, but doesn't show up in the app list. First time asking on stackoverflow. Excuse my english :)

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.neriko.sixhandshakes">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".SixHandshakes"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="vk5536139" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VKUserSearchActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKServiceActivity"
            android:label="ServiceActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/VK.Transparent" />
        <activity
            android:name=".VKDisplayResultActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: anything strange in logcat?

Comment: The main problem is that I have no access to the device atm, so I can't check logcat, when I run it in Bluestacks it seems to be same as always.

Comment: How do you install it?

Comment: Uploading it to dropbox and then downloading it on the device, then installing as usual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out what was causing the problem. `<data android:scheme="vk5536139" />` line seems to be not allowed in the same block with main action and launcher category definition.